# Updating matplotlib using OSGeo4W

Tags: qgis, python

This question has been asked, but I can't seem to find an answer suitable for a non-computer programmer.  A link would be great, or a quick 'how-to'.

I updated to Dufour (2.0.1) and have run into a problem where the python plugin 'matplotlib' requires 'dateutil'.  Message boards have said I can get this by installing 'matplotlib' through OSGeo4w.

A) Is this true?

and

B) If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Dateutil is part of matplotlib on OSGeo4W. To install matplotlib, go to **Advanced install**. From the list of available packages, go to **Libs** and select matplotlib for installation.

[image]

Comment: I've been working on a new plugin and in that plugin I want to use `FigureCanvasTkAgg` something that started to work(?) in `matplotlib 1.5.1`. Is there any reson why matplotlib still is 1.3.1 in OSGeo4W setup?

Comment: @axel_ande OSGeo4W is lagging behind with many Python package versions. You could upgrade it using OSGeo4W Shell and `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`.

Comment: @j08lue Thanks, do you have insight in how osgeo4w will handle QGIS3, when it comes to packages? Or the best way to contribute to get that working? (My plugin is already getting to complex for the prospective users)

Comment: @axel_ande No, but feel free to open a separate thread on this topic

Comment: @axel_ande I unfortunately do not have that insight. Pls point to the new thread when you opened it ;)