# How to install Fiona to read Shapefile attributes with OSGeo4W?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, fiona, osgeo4w

I´m developing a plugin in Python and I need to read the shapefile attributes, so I found the Fiona API and dbfpy also but I don't understand how to install these packages because I install the QGIS through osgeo4W. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 18):

1. Why would you want install [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) if you can use PyQGIS to read the shapefile attributes ?
2. [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) is for reading geometries **and** attributes of a shapefile file (as [PyShp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/)), therefore you don't need [dbfpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbfpy/2.2.0) (look at [Python Script examples for geoprocessing shapefiles without using arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/python-script-examples-for-geoprocessing-shapefiles-without-using-arcpy/64158#64158)).
3. [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) is a Python module so you must install it as any Python module in the site-packages folder of your Python installation as SaultDon says.
4. but as [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) needs to compile C++ code (from GDAL/OGR) to install, you cannot use `pip` or `easy-install` on Windows (no compiler).You can try to install the "ready to use" version of [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona) but it is linked to his version of [GDAL](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal))
5. this procedure works with the standalone version of QGIS.

#### Examples of reading attributes of a shapefile:

With Fiona:

```py
import fiona
features = fiona.open("strati.shp")
features.schema
{'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'PENDAGE', 'int:2'), (u'DIRECTION', 'int:3'), (u'TYPE', 'str:10')])}
for feat in features:
     print feat['properties']

OrderedDict([(u'PENDAGE', 30), (u'DIRECTION', 120), (u'TYPE', u'incl')])
OrderedDict([(u'PENDAGE', 45), (u'DIRECTION', 145), (u'TYPE', u'incl')])
OrderedDict([(u'PENDAGE', 78), (u'DIRECTION', 148), (u'TYPE', u'incl')])
```

With PyShp:

```py
import shapefile
reader = shapefile.Reader("strati.shp") 
fields = reader.fields[1:]
print fields
[['PENDAGE', 'N', 2, 0], ['DIRECTION', 'N', 3, 0], ['TYPE', 'C', 10, 0]]
field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]
schema = dict((d[0],d[1:]) for d in reader.fields[1:])
print schema
{'DIRECTION': ['N', 3, 0], 'PENDAGE': ['N', 2, 0], 'TYPE': ['C', 10, 0]}
for feat in reader.shapeRecords():
    print dict(zip(field_names, sr.record))  

{'DIRECTION': 148, 'PENDAGE': 78, 'TYPE': 'incl'}
{'DIRECTION': 148, 'PENDAGE': 78, 'TYPE': 'incl'}
{'DIRECTION': 148, 'PENDAGE': 78, 'TYPE': 'incl'}
```

with PyQGIS in the Python console:

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()  
fields = layer.pendingFields()  
field_names = [field.name() for field in fields]  
field_types = [field.typeName() for field in fields]
field_precision = [field.precision() for field in fields]
print field_precision
[0,0,0]
print dict(zip(field_names,field_types))
{u'DIRECTION': u'Integer', u'PENDAGE': u'Integer', u'TYPE': u'String'}
schema = dict((field_names[i], {field_types[i]:field_precision[i] if  field_precision[i] > 0 else field_types[i]:'' }) for i in range(len(field_names)))
print schema
{u'DIRECTION': {u'Integer': ''}, u'PENDAGE': {u'Integer': ''}, u'TYPE': {u'String': ''}}
for feat in layer.getFeatures():  
    print dict(zip(field_names, feat.attributes()))

{u'DIRECTION': 120, u'PENDAGE': 30, u'TYPE': u'incl'}
{u'DIRECTION': 145, u'PENDAGE': 45, u'TYPE': u'incl'}
{u'DIRECTION': 148, u'PENDAGE': 78, u'TYPE': u'incl'}
```

With dbfpy:

```py
from dbfpy import dbf
db = dbf.Dbf("strati.dbf")
print db.fieldNames
['PENDAGE', 'DIRECTION', 'TYPE']
print db.fieldDefs
[PENDAGE    N   2   0, DIRECTION  N   3   0, TYPE       C  10   0]  
schema = dict(zip(db.fieldNames,db.fieldDefs))
print schema
{'DIRECTION': DIRECTION  N   3   0, 'PENDAGE': PENDAGE    N   2   0, 'TYPE': TYPE       C  10   0} 
for feat in db:
    print dict(zip(db.fieldNames, feat.asList()))  

{'DIRECTION': 120, 'PENDAGE': 30, 'TYPE': 'incl'}
{'DIRECTION': 145, 'PENDAGE': 45, 'TYPE': 'incl'}
{'DIRECTION': 148, 'PENDAGE': 78, 'TYPE': 'incl'}
```

So you don't need dbfpy or other dbf Python module ([PyPI:dbf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=dbf&submit=search))

Comment: I have the osgeo4w installation. So, I don't need the Fiona to read text attributes?

Comment: @BárbaraDuarte Not necessarily, fiona is simply an option =) Folks here are saying that the QGIS API can read text attributes. There's a nice example in the link from underdark

Comment: Can you give an example of function please?

Comment: I have introduced  an example above

Comment: Thanks for the examples given. I will try with the PyQGIS.

Comment: Just a question, your code is in python console, my is not. So I defined a QgsVectorLayer first, so your layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() can be used as layer = QgsVectorLayer(unicode(inputLayer).encode('utf8'), inputLayer , "ogr") right?

Comment: yes but I cannot help you because I never make plugins (too long for my work, I mainly use the console or scripts in the Processing toolbox). Read the documentation, please.

Answer (score 3):

Update: **Installing Python3 Fiona in OSGeo4W**

1. OSGeo4W installer: install **python3-pip**
2. Environment variables: add GDAL_VERSION = 2.3.2 (or whichever version your OSGeo4W installation currently features)
3. OSGeo4W shell: `call C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\py3_env.bat`
4. OSGeo4W shell: `pip3 install geopandas` (this will error at fiona)
5. From https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona: download Fiona-1.7.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
6. OSGeo4W shell: `pip3 install <path-to-download>\Fiona-1.7.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
7. OSGeo4W shell: `pip3 install geopandas`

---

Old answer:
You can access the attributes using QGIS API. You don't need Fiona to do that.

http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html

Comment: I try with QGIS API but I want to read text attributes.

Comment: @BárbaraDuarte You wrote "I need to read the shapefile attributes". What do you mean with "read text attributes"?

Comment: I want to obtain a list of text attributes. The idea is read each text attribute and assign a number to that attribute.

Comment: the above mentioned link http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html is not found anymore and outdated ...!

Comment: i did the installation process for my qgis 3.4.3 starting wigh https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273870/osgeo4w-shell-with-python3 and then followed the steps for fiona and geopandas install from above "installing python3 fiona in osgeo4w".  install seemed to be successfully according to the messages on screen. the first test via "import geopandas" from within python 3.7. (osgeo4w shell version) resulted in an fiona error: "ImportError: DLL load failed: module not found")

Comment: ... the last 3 lines of the above mentioned error are:  
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 9, in <module>
from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden

Comment: @roberttuw the issue could be due to a wrong version or installation in the wrong python environment. Hard to remote debug without the exact steps. Probably worth a separate question

Comment: @underdark - i've been trying it with python.org 3.6.8 version and pip install, and (!) with OSGeo4W qgis setup / libraries install manager (python 3.7). both versions pretend to install Fiona and geopandas but return exactly the same errors on "import fiona" or "import geopandas". maybe you are right - i will raise a separate question...

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the 32-bit or 64-bit OSGeo4W installer?

You can try installing **setuptools** too and then from the OSGeo4W terminal try executing `easy_install fiona` and `easy_install dbfpy`.

<s>There is a [bug report](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/399) for the 64bit installer because *setuptools* is broken for that one.</s>

---

I found that you can always download the [ez_setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) script and then from the OSGeo4W terminal run it using `python ez_setup.py` - this will install `easy_setup` and it works on OSGeo4W 64-bit.

I've installed dbfpy using `easy_install dbfpy` but [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona) is complaining about missing gdal-config. Troubleshooting that right now and it looks like it can be fixed by setting the needed paths in Fiona's `setup.cfg` file.

Comment: I don't remember but I think the osgeo4W installer is 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will try with the PyQGIS but its important to me to know how to install external packages. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here is what I found works. My mistake was that I tried to install using my independently installed Python rather than Python in QGIS.

1. Right click on OSGeo4W Shell icon and click on "Run as administrator". There seems to be another way (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528020/why-am-i-getting-windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied), but it only gave me access to the independent Python.
2. Install pip by following the pip install section in this: https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation
3. Download Fiona from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (in my case, Fiona‑1.7.2‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl)
4. Run `python -m pip install [path to the whl file downloaded in step 3]`
5. To check, go to the Python directory (e.g., `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\Python27`) and type `pip freeze`. Fiona should appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can install fiona with the osgeo4w installer. The package is called python3-fiona. To do this choose start "osgeo4w-setup.exe" and choose "Advanced Installation" (and confirm the following steps) and then search under "select packages" for the fiona packages. So it is similar to [underdarks solution for matplotlib](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75117/updating-matplotlib-using-osgeo4w).