# Using OSGeo4W shell with Python 3

Tags: python-3, osgeo4w, shell, syntaxerror

I would like to use OSGeo4W shell with Python 3 but when typing `python3` I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I use Python 3?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a not well documented command build into OSGeo4W Shell which sets the shell up to python3 as Luke mentions

```
py3_env
```

Basically it sets your PYTHONHOME and the correct PATH. Then you can call Python3 with `python3`.

```
C:\>py3_env
C:\>SET PYTHONPATH=
C:\>SET PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36
C:\>PATH C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem
C:\>python3
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

---

**Update** with auslander's comment:

To use Python3 with the OSGeo4W shell that comes with QGIS 2 you have to change the file `{path you installed qgis}\etc\ini\python-core.bat`:

```
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36
PATH %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36\Scripts;%PATH%
```

Comment: If you want to do this on Windows with the OSGeo4W shell that comes with QGIS 3, you will have to go into `{path you installed qgis}\etc\ini` and modify `python-core.bat` to reference `Python36` instead of `Python27` in the batch script that sets `PYTHONHOME` and `PATH`. Then call `python3` from the CLI.  However note this will break links to python 2.7 and give you a syntax error if you try to call just `python`.

Comment: @Auslander breaking python 2.7 is not the way to do this. See my answer, just run `py3_env` which sets the shell up for Python 3 automatically.

Comment: @Luke clever! I stand corrected.

Comment: @Luke I've updated my answer. I overlooked the command in the shell and google did not give me any answer. Still, the OSGeo4W shell that comes with QGIS 2 does not have the `py3_env`

Comment: Before qgis 3 (which requires python 3) was released there was only a need for a single version of python as qgis 2 requires python 2. OSGeo4W couldn't really drop qgis 2 so they had to find some way of supporting both qgis 2 + python 2 and qgis 3 + python 3.

Comment: If you use QGIS 3.6 - keep in mind it work on python 3.7 not 3.6. So you have to change paths accordingly.

Answer (score 37):

There's no need to edit batch files (and break python 2.7 in the process) or set environment variables manually.

Just run `py3_env` which sets the shell up for Python 3 automatically, then run `python3`.

From a OSGeo4W shell with just python 2 & 3 installed:

```
C:\> o-help
                   -={ OSGeo4W Shell Commands }=-

       dllupdate           pip3                sqlite3
       easy_install3       python              textreplace
       nircmd              python3             vcredist_2015_x64
       nircmdc             pythonw             xxmklink
       osgeo4w-setup       pythonw3


       make-bat-for-py   py3_env  <<<=== This is the command you want
       o-help            setup-test
       o4w_env           setup



C:\>python3
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000013e8 (most recent call first):
^C

C:\>py3_env
C:\>python3

Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make the change permanent you can modify the batch file OSGeo4W.bat located in your QGIS (or OSGEO) directory and just add:

```
call "py3_env"
```

below the line calling

```
call "%~dp0\bin\o4w_env.bat"
```

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't happen during install?

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure that `py3_env` to initiate the python with OSGEO Shell is not working. The right command is  `pythonw` if you have the current version of QGIS (3.20).