# QGIS 3.0 migration - unable to install PyPDF2

Tags: pyqgis-3, pip

I am migrating my Plugin to QGIS 3.0. Currently a bit stuck trying to install PyPDF2. I have been trying different things for the last couple of hours or more, without success.

I have got another version of Python installed (3.5, which I use for other things and 2.7...partly - I uninstalled it via Windows today although the folder is still there at C:\Python27. Probably I have to manually delete the remainder) Anyway I believe it should be quite possible to run more than one version. I have done it before.

QGIS uses Python 3.6, here: C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\apps\Python36

So in the standard scenario I would install PyPDF2 from OSGeo4W Shell. I run OSGeo4W Shell and type o-help which shows a list of available modules including pip3 (although not pip). I presume I should use pip3 to install PyPDF2. So I type this command:

```
pip3 install PyPDF2
```

I get the familiar message `'Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"''`

I have trawled the forums for solutions to this but the ones I have tried have not worked for me. It sounds as if this should be fixed by upgrading pip, from what I understand(?)

If I run `pip3 install --upgrade pip3` it doesn't work either. Same error, as might be expected

I have tried to run pip / pip3 from a command window opened from the path `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\apps\Python36\Scripts`

If I do `./pip3 install PyPDF2` from a Powershell window there I get the same error again.

If I go up one level to the Python36 folder and run `python -m pip3 install PyPDF2` I get the error `No module named pip3`

And so and so forth.

In an effort to make sure I am using the correct (QGIS) version of Python I added the '\QGIS 3.0\apps\Python36' folder to the PYTHON_HOME variable and added %PYTHON_HOME% to the Path variable.

How can I install PyPDF2??

Answer (score 0):

Although I still don't understand how to properly resolve the problems I had installing PyPDF2 for QGIS 3.0 / Python 3.6, I have found a workaround. I referred to the PyPDF2 documentation and saw that it is described as a pure Python library without any external dependencies. Since I had it installed for my 'main' (non-QGIS) Python version, which is 3.5, I guessed that I could simply copy it across.

I copied the folder PyPDF2 from

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\apps\Python36\Lib\site-packages
```

It works.