# Which Python libraries come preinstalled with a fresh standard QGIS 3 installation?

Tags: python, qgis-3

Since I am currently developing a QGIS Plugin that uses an external python library (Scikit-image), **I was wondering, if there is a list of python libraries that come preinstalled with a standard QGIS installation?**

(I know how to install additional libraries (See: [Installing external python packages for QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282685/installing-external-python-packages-for-qgis-3?rq=1)), but it would be nice, if the user of the plugin does not have to handle the installation of additional libraries. I mean I could also try to automatically install or include them, as described here: [Development of a plugin which depends on an external Python library](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/196002/development-of-a-plugin-which-depends-on-an-external-python-library), but to know, what is available would be good to know.)

I did not find such a list yet and since I run a OSGeo4W advanced installed QGIS 3.16 version on Windows 10, that I customized, I am not able to answer this question because I already installed a lot of additional libraries myself.

Otherwise I could just check the folder containing the libraries, which is in my case this one:
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages

In Windows, I can list the plugin folders this way:
In cmd prompt change to this directory using

```
cd C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages
```

then get the list of the containing folders with the command:

C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages>`dir /a:d /b`

Interesting would be to know, if **rasterio** or **xarray** / **rioxarray** are preinstalled libraries or not.

Comment: Don't you want to say Python libraries instead of Python plugins? In QGIS context, there is native Python plugins `[name for name, plugin in installer_data.plugins.mPlugins.items() if plugin['readonly']]` and the others `[name for name, plugin in installer_data.plugins.mPlugins.items() if not plugin['readonly']]` whereas when you mention `Scikit-image`, it's a 3rd party Python library.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. You are absolutely right, I was too tired and mixed it up. I meant 3rd party Python libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a list at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/.docker/qgis3-build-deps.dockerfile#L54

> Interesting would be to know, if rasterio or xarray / rioxarray are preinstalled libraries or not.

None are installed e.g rasterio search https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?q=rasterio (RasterIO but GDAL), xarray search https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?q=xarray