# QGIS print layout - export legend items to Excel

Tags: qgis, print-composer, excel

I have the well-built legend in the QGIS print composer, as my project includes more than 20 layers. Because the legend in front layout doesn't match our legend patterns produced in Excel I am wondering about the option of exporting these legend items to MS Excel.

[image]

Is there any reasonable and quite quick way of exporting the print layout legend items to Excel?

Comment: Why excel? Would a PDF file suffice?

Comment: No, because it needs additional alteration in Excel.

Comment: Are those legend items in excel actually lines and polygons or are they pictures/images?

Comment: My initial thought would be to save your layers as a "Save Layer Style" (.qml or .sld) and then perhaps extract from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting question. I couldn't resist having a play around with this. I have hacked together a Python script (cobbled from different sources) which should take care of this for you.

**Note:** you will need to install one third party Python module: XlsxWriter. The best way to do this may vary depending on your OS and your QGIS version and installation. I installed QGIS on Windows with the new OSGeo4W installer, but with some tweaking this should work for any Windows install.

**Option 1:** I use a batch file which looks like this:

```
@echo off
rem Root OSGEO4W home dir to the same directory this script exists in
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\python-qgis.bat"

rem List available o4w programs
rem but only if osgeo4w called without parameters
@echo on
@if [%1]==[] (echo run o-help for a list of available commands & cd /d "%~dp0" & cmd.exe /k) else (cmd /c "%*")
```

You can copy this into a text editor and edit if necessary. The line `SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=` should point to the directory containing the `bin` folder where your QGIS application is located (in my case it is `C:\OSGeo4W`. Next, this batch file calls another batch file (the one QGIS uses to set the pyqgis environment) so check that there is a `python-qgis.bat` file located in the bin folder. Depending on your version it may be `python-qgis-ltr.bat` so edit the batch file above accordingly. Save this batch file somewhere (give it a name like `OSGeo4W_pyqgis.bat`) and double click to run. The shell will open up to a Python prompt. type `quit()` and hit enter. Now type `pip install XlsxWriter` and hit enter. That is how I installed XlsxWriter and it worked for me.

**Option 2:** Alternatively, you could try running the following lines inside the QGIS Python console (this may indeed be the most straight forward):

```py
import pip

pip.main(['install','XlsxWriter'])
```

You can check [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282685/installing-external-python-packages-for-qgis-3) and related ones for more info but again, depending on your installation, some discussions may be out of date because with the new OSGeo4W installer, there is no longer a `py3_env.bat`.

Assuming you have managed to install `XlsxWriter` in the Python used by QGIS, you can now paste the following script into an editor in the Python console, change the export path and layout name, and click run.

```py
import xlsxwriter
from io import BytesIO

EXPORT_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\Output\\legend.xlsx'# Path to save your spreadsheet
LAYOUT_NAME = 'Layout Name'# Name of your layout

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(EXPORT_PATH)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

def convert_icon(icon, size=None, fmt='PNG'):
    '''
    This function modified from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789856/python-convert-qt-qicon-into-jpeg
    Credit: stackoverflow member ekhumoro
    '''
    if isinstance(icon, QIcon):
        if size is None:
            size = icon.availableSizes()[0]
        pixmap = icon.pixmap(size)
        
    elif isinstance(icon, QPixmap):
        pixmap = icon
    array = QtCore.QByteArray()
    buffer = QtCore.QBuffer(array)
    buffer.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    pixmap.save(buffer, fmt)
    buffer.close()
    return array.data()

project = QgsProject.instance()
mgr = project.layoutManager()
layout = mgr.layoutByName(LAYOUT_NAME)
legend = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]
model = legend.model()
sheet_row = 1
for i in range(model.columnCount()):
    for j, l in enumerate(model.rootGroup().findLayers()):
        index = model.index(j, i)
        legend_nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(l)
        if len(legend_nodes) == 1:
            icon = model.data(index, 1)
            lyr_name = model.data(index, 2)
            if icon.availableSizes():
                img_data = convert_icon(icon)
                io_data = BytesIO(img_data)# BytesIO object
                icon_cell = f'A{sheet_row}'
                worksheet.insert_image(icon_cell, 'image.png', {'image_data': io_data, 'x_offset': 15, 'y_offset': 2})
                lyr_name_cell = f'B{sheet_row}'
                sheet_row+=1
                worksheet.write(lyr_name_cell, str(lyr_name))
                worksheet.set_column('B:B', 30)
            sheet_row+=1
        if len(legend_nodes) > 1:
            subhdg = model.data(index, 2)
            subhdg_cell = f'A{sheet_row}'
            sheet_row+=1
            worksheet.write(subhdg_cell, str(subhdg))
            for n in legend_nodes:
                node_index = model.legendNode2index(n)
                icon = model.data(node_index, 1)
                cat_name = model.data(node_index, 2)
                img_data = convert_icon(icon)
                io_data = BytesIO(img_data)
                icon_cell = f'A{sheet_row}'
                cat_name_cell = f'B{sheet_row}'
                sheet_row+=1
                worksheet.insert_image(icon_cell, 'image.png', {'image_data': io_data, 'x_offset': 15, 'y_offset': 2})
                worksheet.write(cat_name_cell, str(cat_name))
                worksheet.set_column('B:B', 30)
            sheet_row+=1
            
workbook.close()
```

See below for example results with a test layout legend.
My legend in the layout looks like this:

[image]

The resulting spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

**References:**

[Python: convert QT QIcon into jpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789856/python-convert-qt-qicon-into-jpeg)

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images_bytesio.html

[xlsxwriter: how to load a BytesIO png files created with matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949725/xlsxwriter-how-to-load-a-bytesio-png-files-created-with-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: pip is not recognized in OsGeo4W Shell, is there a different way of importing this library?

Comment: @MKR, I have edited my answer with more details about installing additional Python modules for QGIS. I don't know anything about your os, qgis version or installation method so maybe you should try option 2 first

Comment: thx for this amazing script! very well written and very easy to use!