# Directly exporting rule-based count results in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, count

I have hundreds of rules specifying ranges of polygon areas. I would like to create a table of the ranges and their values outside of QGIS and since these results are exactly what I am after I would like to export them directly from the layer properties here. I know there are tools like statistics by category which are useful but it would be far easier and quicker if I could simply use these count results directly.

[image]

Comment: Just label and rule, or all table including count, duplicate count?

Comment: Thanks, I am after the rule and count.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the filter expression of each rule with this script. Copy-paste it to the script editor of the Python console and click <kbd>Run</kbd>

Make sure the layer is selected in the Layers Panel, and that it is not in edit mode, else the filter will not be applied.

```py
# get layer
lyr = iface.activeLayer() 

# get the rule-based rendered from the layer
r = lyr.renderer()

# get the root rule
root = r.rootRule()

# iterate through rules
for rule in root.children():
    # get the rule filter expression
    exp = rule.filterExpression()
    
    # set the rule filter on the layer
    lyr.setSubsetString(exp)
    
    # count filtered features
    count = lyr.featureCount()
    
    # reset the filter
    lyr.setSubsetString('')
    
    print(f'rule: {exp} | count: {count}')
    
    ## do something with rules (save to text file)
```

Output:

```
rule: "code" = 'A' | count: 12425
rule: "code" = 'B' | count: 12580
rule: "code" = 'C' | count: 12298
rule: "code" = 'D' | count: 12618
rule: "code" = 'E' | count: 12534
rule: "code" = 'F' | count: 12441
```

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on my other answer, and with the help of [this excellent answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/422305/128665) by [Ben W](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/100254/ben-w), I came up with a script to save the rules, counts, and symbology to an Excel spreadsheet.

It relies on one non-native library, XlsxWriter. The easiest way to install it is to open the OsGeo4W shell (via the Start Menu on Windows) and use:

```
pip install XlsxWriter
```

[image]

Then run the script in the Script Editor in the QGIS Python console.

```py
import os
import xlsxwriter
from io import BytesIO

# path to save images
IMG_PATH = r'D:\OneDrive\geodata\symbols'

# path to save the spreadsheet
EXPORT_PATH = r'D:\OneDrive\geodata\rules.xlsx'

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(EXPORT_PATH)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

def convert_icon(icon, size=None, fmt='PNG'):
    '''
    This function modified from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789856/python-convert-qt-qicon-into-jpeg
    Credit: stackoverflow member ekhumoro
    '''
    if size is None:
        size = 18
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(icon)
    pixmap = pixmap.scaledToWidth(size)
        
    array = QtCore.QByteArray()
    buffer = QtCore.QBuffer(array)
    buffer.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    pixmap.save(buffer, fmt)
    buffer.close()
    return array.data()

# write the spreadsheet headers
worksheet.write('A1', 'symbol')
worksheet.write('B1', 'label')
worksheet.write('C1', 'rule')
worksheet.write('D1', 'count')

# get layer
lyr = iface.activeLayer() 

# get the rule-based rendered from the layer
r = lyr.renderer()

# get the root rule
root = r.rootRule()

# set the spreadsheet row to enter data
sheet_row = 2

# iterate through rules
for rule in root.children():
    
    # get various attributes from rule
    sym = rule.symbol()
    lab = rule.label()
    exp = rule.filterExpression()
        
    # set the rule filter on the layer
    lyr.setSubsetString(exp)
    # count filtered features
    count = lyr.featureCount()
    # reset the filter
    lyr.setSubsetString('')
    
    # get rule symbol as image
    img = sym.asImage(QSize(40,40))

    # optionally save symbols as png
    img.save(
        os.path.join(
            IMG_PATH, 
            (exp.replace('<=', 'lte')
                .replace('>=', 'gte')
                .replace('<>', 'not')
                .replace('<', 'lt')
                .replace('>', 'gt')
                .replace('=', 'eq')                
                .replace('.', '_')
                .replace('"','')
                .replace("'", '') + '.png')
        )
    )
        
    # convert QImage to QByteArray
    img_data = convert_icon(img)
    
    # convert to BytesIO object
    io_data = BytesIO(img_data) 
    
    # assign cells for data
    icon_cell  = f'A{sheet_row}'
    label_cell = f'B{sheet_row}'
    rule_cell  = f'C{sheet_row}'
    count_cell = f'D{sheet_row}'
    
    # insert symbol and corresponding data into cells
    worksheet.insert_image(icon_cell, 'image.png', {'image_data': io_data, 'x_offset': 15, 'y_offset': 3})
    worksheet.write(label_cell, lab)
    worksheet.write(rule_cell, exp)
    worksheet.write(count_cell, count)
    
    # set the width of specific columns to accommodate data
    worksheet.set_column('B:B', 20)  
    worksheet.set_column('C:C', 40)  
    
    # go to next row of spreadsheet
    sheet_row+=1

# commit the changes to the workbook
workbook.close()
```

The spreadsheet:

[image]

The saved image files:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Matt, this looks fantastic. Unfortunately I'm having trouble running the script. I seem to have successfully installed xlsxwriter (ran pip.main(['install','XlsxWriter']) in the python console and output said successfully installed), then when I run the script it fails at the beginning with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter' (I can't paste the output here as it goes over character limit).

Comment: [Ben details a few ways](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/422305/128665) to install the module in his answer. I found the easiest way was through the OsGeo4W shell (see update to my answer). Is it a requirement that it must be installed via the script?

Comment: I tried first through OsGeo4W shell as Ben writes but doing that I got the error msg it is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc. 

I looked for other ways and found that the command python -m pip install XlsxWriter worked.

I don't know if it has to be installed via a script, it would be good if there was perhaps another way (I haven't so far found one).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue, as using OsGeo4W shell works fine for me. I just tried with another library (`flickrapi`) and I can import it in the QGIS Python console directly after `pip install flickrapi` in the OsGeo4W shell.

Comment: Thanks Matt, got it up and running! What if there was another level of rules and counts within the rules ie. children of children, could that be shown as well?