# PyQGIS standalone script using QGIS 3.2

Tags: pyqgis, batch, python-3, standalone, syntaxerror

I want to work with PyQGIS Python 3 using QGIS 3.2 standalone install. I created a simple batch file to work with PyQGIS but I have some errors.

Here's the batch file:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1\lib
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36


SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\bin\pycharm.exe
start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Error is:

```
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Sounds like python 2.7 is [getting called instead of python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472223). Update your batch script to call [`py3_env`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277842/2856). Not sure where  it is, I don't have access to osgeo4w currently, probably somewhere like `call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\py3_env`

Answer (score 1):

Jessie, I suspect there may be a problem with this line in your batch file:

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2
```

try setting it to your OSGeo4W64 root folder like below:

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by incorrect PyCharm setup, check this answer: [Why does QGIS 3.2 "native:extractvertices" algorithm not work properly in standalone script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286281/why-does-qgis-3-2-nativeextractvertices-algorithm-not-work-properly-in-standa/289964#289964)

Comment: @Luke True. Answer edited.