# Using a .bat file to run a QGIS python program

Tags: pyqgis

I have a python script that runs in QGIS that I would like to run without opening QGIS. The script is as follows:

**QGIS_Zonal_Stats_osGeo.py**

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

sys.path.append("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins")

from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = today - one_day
yesterday_date = yesterday.strftime('"%Y-%m-%d"').lstrip("0").replace(" 0", " ")
yesterday_date_name = yesterday.strftime("%B_%d_%Y").lstrip("0").replace(" 0", " ")

rasterFilePath = 'C:/Users/bboyko/Desktop/precipitation_download/Daily_Rainfall/' + str(yesterday_date_name) + '.tif'

polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/bboyko/Desktop/precipitation_download/candidate_singlepart.shp', 
'candidate_singlepart', "ogr") 

rasterLayer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterFilePath, str(yesterday_date_name))

zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterLayer, 'rain_', 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean)

zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

And this is the .bat file I am using:

**Launch.bat**

```
SET QGIS=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis
SET PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37
SET PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

python C:\Users\bboyko\Desktop\precipitation_download\QGIS_Zonal_Stats_Three_osGeo.py
pause
```

When I run the batch file this is the message I receive in a command prompt:

```
C:\Users\bboyko\Desktop\precipitation_download>python C:\Users\bboyko\Desktop\precipitation_download\QGIS_Zonal_Stats_Three_osGeo.py
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is the mistake coming from my python script or my .bat file, of from some other issue I haven't considered.

Comment: You need to call `py3_env` in your batch file, see [OSGeo4W shell with python3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273870/osgeo4w-shell-with-python3)

Answer (score 2):

Change your **Launch.bat** for something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

python C:\Users\bboyko\Desktop\precipitation_download\QGIS_Zonal_Stats_Three_osGeo.py
pause
```

It should work