# How to initialize the QGIS from standalone script?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I tried to initialize QGIS  from a standalone script, but it's giving the error (find in an image).
[image]

I reinstalled, but the same issue occurred.

code:

```
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_airports_layer, "Airports layer", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
qgs.exitQgis()
```

How can I initialize correctly?

Comment: Please remember to always include the exact error message in the body of the Question as text. Images can't be indexed for search. Our purpose is to compile answers to GIS questions; hiding the question from others in effect hides the answer, and therefore discourages answering the question.

Comment: Under Windows OS you need to start python with correct environment. You can use a batch-file to do this. Read here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322195/using-a-bat-file-to-run-a-qgis-python-program

Comment: @AndreasMüller I used the batch file as mentioned  in an answer. code is running without any error   but qgis application is not opening

Comment: You can't open QGIS this way, you'll be able to use QGIS-Elements that way. Make sure to read the Pyqis-Cookbook from the QGIS-Website!