# Reset Python version to default

Tags: pyqgis, installation, osgeo4w

Regrettably, I followed a tutorial and set PYTHONPATH to qgis\apps\python. After doing so, typing python -V in the OSGeo4W Shell gives Python 2.7.14.
Previously, the result was Python 3.7.0, which is the version I want.
I deleted the PYTHONPATH variable and rebooted my pc, but version 2.7 remains the default in the shell.
How can I restore Python 3 to the default again.

Comment: You can check your PATH environment variable, the python version you are getting now is the first one your PATH can find, in this case 2.7

Comment: It would be nice if it were that simple, but that's not it. The python version on my system is 3.7.3, and that takes first place. I don't use version 2 since its end of life. The python I am accessing is associated with qgis, which has both version 2 and 3, and runs from the OSGeo4W Shell.

Comment: I just found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273870/using-osgeo4w-shell-with-python-3).
I just needed to run py3_env.
Now python -V returns Python 3.7.0